# Find a string in file with combinaison of loop For and If

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm beginner on python, and I can't managed to get my loop and if condition working on this case as below.

I'm searching for a server passed in argument (host), If founded it return, the string in column 16th, if not : not founded. In my code it returns not founded in the loop, I just want only one time.

I also tried with one break without luck.

Thanks for your help.

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split('`')
        if host in line:
          model = parts[16]
          print("You have selected this server model: " + host + " " + model)
        else:
          print("not founded")
```

Comment: How does `file` look like?, btw python indexing starts form zero so maybe you want `parts[15]`

Comment: without knowing how the file looks like, we can't help much. The one thing I can say is that doing `parts = line.split('\`')` would make more sense inside the `if host in line:`.

Comment: Also desired output is very needed

Comment: did you try set break in if and set for loop else not found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print `'not found'` only after finishing the loop without finding a match, and you should `break` the loop as soon as you find a match. For this purpose you can use the `for-else` construct:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split('`')
        if host in line:
            model = parts[16]
            print("You have selected this server model: " + host + " " + model)
            break
    else:
        print("not found")
```

Comment: Thanks, It made the trick, I thought I had to close to leave the else under the loop.